# How can we get all the equations related to a vertical parabola if we just know the standard equation of a parabola whose axis is the x-axis?

Tags: conic-sections

Suppose I know all the equations related to a parabola defined as $$y^2= 4ax$$. By "all equations", I meant to say the equation of tangent,
normal, chord of contact, polar of a point.. everything related to just that form.

**So can I just use all those above equations somehow to get all the equations related to a parabola defined as $$x^2 =4by$$ ?**  $$Or$$

How should I transform all the equations related to a parabola ($y^2=4ax$) to get the equations for the parabola ($x^2=4by$) ?

I have a test and need quick help. So sorry for this stupid question.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you need to do is rotate $\pi/2$ radians:
$x= \cos(\pi/2)x'+ \sin(\pi/2)y'= y'$
$y= -\sin(\pi/2)x'+ \cos(\pi/2)y'= -x'$

So $y^2= 4ax$ becomes $(-x')^2= x'^2= 4ay'$

Comment: so do you mean that for all the equations like equation of a tangent or normal I just need to do a rotational shift and replace x and y with x' and y' ?